# Form is not submitting php and html

Tags: php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog, submit

Good afternoon, I have a web project, ready, and the form validated with ajax and jquery, have also a PHP function where sending all data on my form, and I have to rest a modal window boostratp, activated by clicking on the submit, the problem is that jquery is blocking the passage of the form to php and is not sending only shows the modal. I guess I activate the jquery from php, but not exactly how to do it

this my form:

```js
    // What to do on submit - example of success message

    // -------------------------------------------------

    submitHandler: function(form) {

      $('#successForm').modal('show');

      return false;  

    }  

  });


// Reset the contact form when success message shown as bootstrap modal is dismissed

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$('#successForm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {

  $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");

  $('#contactForm .form-group').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');

});
```

```html
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/js-theme/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Include all plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js-bootstrap/modal.js"></script>


<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="enviar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_top">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback wow flipInX" data-wow-duration="600ms">
                      <label for="nombre">Nombre*</label>
                      <input id="nombre" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="" aria-label="nombre" />
                      <span id="nombre1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .form-group -->
    
                    <div class="form-group wow flipInX" data-wow-duration="900ms">
                      <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                      <input id="celular" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="celular" value="" placeholder="" aria-label="celular" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .form-group -->
    
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback wow flipInX" data-wow-duration="800ms">
                      <label for="email">Email*</label>
                      <input id="email" class="form-control input-lg" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="" aria-label="email" />
                      <span id="email1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .form-group -->
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback wow flipInX" data-wow-duration="1000ms">
                      <label for="mensaje">Mensaje*</label>
                      <textarea id="mensaje" class="form-control" name="mensaje" rows="10" ></textarea>
                      <span id="mensaje1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .form-group -->
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="form-group wow zoomInDown" data-wow-duration="800ms">
                      <button id="submitContact" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="reset">Borrar</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .form-group -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- end .text-center -->
                </form>





    <!-- Modal success on submit -->
    <div class="theme-submit-success-modal">
      <div class="modal fade" id="successForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="successFormModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="text-center">
                <span class="fa fa-comments-o"></span>
              </div>
              <h4 class="text-center" name="modal_contact" id="successFormModalLabel">Enviado Con Éxito</h4>
              <p class="text-center">Gracias por contactarnos, en breve contestaremos a su mensaje. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might want to post a shorter example. Cut away stuff that isn't important to the problem, like the plugins. They make it harder to test your example.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? Either JS or PHP should be throwing a hint of where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You should start learning how to make websites. So much code for a simple form?!

You better show the modal after the form is sent not just submitted, I think.

Is there a reason for returning false here:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#successForm').modal('show');
    return false;  
}
```

This maybe preventing execution of other necessary code.